# Flex Air, static main window reference?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, air, flex4

As I can get a reference to the main window of an Air Flex application within a component? (The component is not in the main MXML)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as WindowedApplication for flex4.  Should do 'er.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var topLevelApplication : Application = Application.application as WindowedApplication
```

Reference: 
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/Application.html#application

---

In Flex 4, you should use the [topLevelApplication](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/FlexGlobals.html?filter_flex=4#topLevelApplication) property of the [FlexGlobals](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/FlexGlobals.html?filter_flex=4) class, something like this:

```
var topLevelApplication : Application = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as WindowedApplication
```

Comment: Hi:

Tanks for answer...

but spark.components.Application has no application property....

Im in flex 4.

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly.  In flex 4 use FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication .